# G is a connected omega-stable group of finite Morley rank then its derived group is definable and connected

Tags: group-theory, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am reading Lascar's article "Omega-stable groups" in the book of Bouscaren "Model Theory and Algebraic Geometry". In section 5, he applies the indecomposability theorem to show that If $G$ is a connected $\omega$-stable group of finite Morley rank, then its derived subgroup $[G,G]$ is definable and connected. There are some points in the proof that I can not make it clear.

- He defines $Y_a=\{{ba^{-1}b:b\in G\}}$ and claims that it is indecomposable. However, I don't understand why this set is definable (before going to prove the decomposability).
- He used the fact that if $G$ is connected and $H$ is a normal definable subgroup then $G/H$  is connected. I don't know how to prove it. The obstruction is that $G/H$ might not be definable, and hence if we take $N$ to be a definable subgroup of finite index of $G/H$, then its preimage in $G$ might not be definable in $G$ (although it is of finite index).
- He also mentioned that $[G,G]$ is always definable without the assumption $G$ being connected (without proof). To prove it, I write
  $$G=\bigsqcup_{g_i\in I} g_iG, a=g_ia', b=g_jb'$$
  and then $$[G,G]=<g_i Y_{g_jb'}g_i^{-1}b'^{-1}g_j^{-1}:g_i,g_j\in I, b'\in G^0>, Y_{g_jb'}=\{a'g_jb'a'^{-1}:a'\in G^0\}$$
  where $G^0$ is the connected component of $G$. So, similar to Lascar's proof, for each $g_i,g_j,b'$, the set $Y_{g_jb'}$ is indecomposable, hence $[G,G]$ is connected and definable. However, it seems that $[G,G]$ is not always connected (for example in the case of algebraic groups). I don't understand what is the problem in this argument.

I believe I am missing some points involving definability, especially the imaginaries, right?

Comment: Does Lascar assume that the background theory eliminates imaginaries?

Comment: $Y_a$ is defined by the formula $\exists y\,(x=ya^{-1}y)$. This formula uses $a\in G$ as a parameter, so $Y_a$ is a definable (with parameters) subset of $G$.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind of a connected algebraic group $G$ such that $[G,G]$ fails to be connected? I don't think this happens...

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry, I wrote wrongly. I edited. My third question does not involve the connectedness of $G$. I don't have an example in mind now.

Comment: Yes, Lascar uses the theory of imaginaries. I get your point, so $G/H$ is definable in $T^{eq}$.